# Proof of Kuratowski-Wojdyslawski theorem

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

I was reading the Wikipedia page on [Kuratowski Embedding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski_embedding), and the following result is stated:

> The **Kuratowski–Wojdysławski** theorem states that every bounded metric space $X$ is isometric to a closed subset of a convex subset of some Banach space. (N.B. the image of this embedding is closed in the convex subset, not necessarily in the Banach space.) Here we use the isometry $\Psi : X \to C_b(X)$ defined by $\Psi(x)(y) = d(x,y)$ for all $x,y\in X$.
>   The convex set mentioned above is the convex hull of $\Psi(X)$.

I couldn't find any reference with the proof of closedness of $\Psi(X)$ in its convex hull, nor prove it myself.

I tried using the characterization of the convex hull of a set $A$ (in some vector space) as $$co(A)=\left\{\sum_{i=1}^kt_ia_i:k\geq 1,t_i\geq 0, \sum_{i=1}^k t_i=1, a_i\in A\right\},$$
but I didn't get anywhere.

Can someone help me with the proof of this theorem?

Comment: We need completeness of $X$ as well, I believe. It is stated as such in Bessaga and Pelczynski's book.

Comment: To prove that it's a closed set in the convex hull which characterization do you want to use ?